# Telerik Radgrid on Partial Ajaxifying

Tags: telerik-grid

I've 2 radgrid's in my page.I need to update 2 radgrids simultaneously. when a button in radgrid1 is clicked I need to populate the row to radgrid 2 and vice versa.My code does the update but I've an issue,when a button is clicked from **radgrid1 lastrow** the row is not appended to radgrid 2 and i don't see the row in radgrid 1 aswell.This happens only with lastrow,similarly when a lastrow button clicked in radgrid 2 it's missing to show it in my radgrid 1.otherwise any row clickevent from top or midrow is working fine only when clicked on lastrow i see it missing and appears along with next toprow clicked row.I need to know the reason what causes this misbehaviour only on my radgrid lastrow.

```
 <telerik:RadFormDecorator ID="RadFormDecorator1" runat="server" Skin="Default"  EnableRoundedCorners="False" DecoratedControls="All" />

<telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server" DefaultLoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1">
    <AjaxSettings>

          <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadGrid1">
           <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadGrid1" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1">
                </telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>

         <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadGrid2">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadGrid2" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1">
                </telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>



        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadGrid1LinkButton">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadGrid2" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1">
                </telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadGrid1" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1">
                </telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>

         <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadGrid2LinkButton">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadGrid1" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1">
                </telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadGrid2" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1">
                </telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>


    </AjaxSettings>
</telerik:RadAjaxManager>
<telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel ID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" runat="server">
</telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel>







<h3 style="text-align:left"><i class="icon-group"></i>&nbsp Shared With</h3><br />

<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" 

    Width="100%" OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource" AllowSorting="True" DataKeyNames="CartId" 

    PageSize="10" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="True" AllowMultiRowSelection="True" runat="server" GridLines="None">

    <MasterTableView Width="100%" AllowMultiColumnSorting="true" Summary="RadGrid table" DataKeyNames="CartId">
   <Columns>
   <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="UserNameTemplateColumn" HeaderText="UserName" SortExpression="UserName" >


   <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="UserNamelbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UserName")%>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="DateTemplateColumn" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="Date" >
     <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="RequestDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Date")%>'></asp:Label>

   </ItemTemplate>
  </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

   <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="TemplateColumn1" HeaderText="add user"
                AllowFiltering="false">
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>

    <ItemTemplate>

   <asp:LinkButton ID="RadGrid1LinkButton" 
    OnCommand="AddUser" CommandName="AddUser" runat="server"  CommandArgument='<%# Eval("CartId")%>' >

   </asp:LinkButton>


   </ItemTemplate>

   </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>


   </Columns>

    </MasterTableView>

   <PagerStyle Mode="NextPrevAndNumeric"></PagerStyle>

</telerik:RadGrid>



<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid2"  OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid2_NeedDataSource"   AllowSorting="True" DataKeyNames="CartId" 

    PageSize="10" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="True" AllowMultiRowSelection="True" runat="server" GridLines="None">

    <MasterTableView Width="100%" AllowMultiColumnSorting="true" Summary="RadGrid table" DataKeyNames="RecepientlearningCartId">
   <Columns>
   <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="UserNameTemplateColumn" HeaderText="UserName" SortExpression="UserName" >




     <ItemTemplate>

    <asp:Label ID="UserNamelbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UserName")%>'></asp:Label>

   </ItemTemplate>
  </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
  <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="DateTemplateColumn" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="Date" >
     <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Date" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Date")%>'></asp:Label>

   </ItemTemplate>
  </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

  <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="TemplateColumn1" HeaderText="Revoke Share"
                AllowFiltering="false">
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>


    <ItemTemplate>

  <asp:LinkButton ID="radGrid2LinkButton"  
   OnCommand="Removeuser" CommandName="Removeuser" runat="server"  CommandArgument='<%# Eval("CartId")%>' >

   </asp:LinkButton>


   </ItemTemplate>

   </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>


   </Columns>

    </MasterTableView>

   <PagerStyle Mode="NextPrevAndNumeric"></PagerStyle>

</telerik:RadGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code snippet.

.ASPX

```
<telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel ID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" runat="server">
</telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel>
<telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
    <AjaxSettings>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadGrid1">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadGrid1" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" />
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadGrid2" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" />
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadGrid2">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadGrid2" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" />
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadGrid1" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" />
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
    </AjaxSettings>
</telerik:RadAjaxManager>
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" Width="100%" OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource"
    AllowSorting="True" DataKeyNames="ID" PageSize="10" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    AllowPaging="True" AllowMultiRowSelection="True" runat="server" GridLines="None">
    <MasterTableView Width="100%" AllowMultiColumnSorting="true" Summary="RadGrid table"
        DataKeyNames="ID">
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="UserNameTemplateColumn" HeaderText="UserName"
                SortExpression="UserName">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="UserNamelbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name")%>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="DateTemplateColumn" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="Date">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="RequestDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name")%>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="TemplateColumn1" HeaderText="add user" AllowFiltering="false">
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="RadGrid1LinkButton" OnCommand="AddUser" CommandName="AddUser"
                        Text="click here" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID")%>'>
                    </asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
        </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
    <PagerStyle Mode="NextPrevAndNumeric"></PagerStyle>
</telerik:RadGrid>
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid2" OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid2_NeedDataSource" AllowSorting="True"
    DataKeyNames="CartId" PageSize="10" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="True"
    AllowMultiRowSelection="True" runat="server" GridLines="None">
    <MasterTableView Width="100%" AllowMultiColumnSorting="true" Summary="RadGrid table"
        DataKeyNames="ID">
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="UserNameTemplateColumn" HeaderText="UserName"
                SortExpression="UserName">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="UserNamelbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name")%>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="DateTemplateColumn" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="Date">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Date" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name")%>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="TemplateColumn1" HeaderText="Revoke Share"
                AllowFiltering="false">
                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="radGrid2LinkButton" OnCommand="Removeuser" CommandName="Removeuser"
                        Text="click here" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID")%>'>
                    </asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
        </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
    <PagerStyle Mode="NextPrevAndNumeric"></PagerStyle>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

.ASPX.CS

```
protected void RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    dynamic data = new[] {
        new { ID = 1, Name =DateTime.Now.ToString()},
        new { ID = 2, Name = "Name2"},
        new { ID = 3, Name = "Name3"},
         new { ID = 4, Name = "Name4"},
        new { ID = 5, Name = "Name5"}
    };

    RadGrid1.DataSource = data;
}

protected void RadGrid2_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    dynamic data = new[] {
        new { ID = 1, Name =DateTime.Now.ToString()},
        new { ID = 2, Name = "Name2"},
        new { ID = 3, Name = "Name3"},
         new { ID = 4, Name = "Name4"},
        new { ID = 5, Name = "Name5"}
    };

    RadGrid2.DataSource = data;
}



protected void AddUser(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    RadGrid1.Rebind();
    RadGrid2.Rebind();
}
protected void Removeuser(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    RadGrid1.Rebind();
    RadGrid2.Rebind();
}
```

Comment: I've tried your code.but dint work.Din't know what really causes this issue.

Comment: I have updated above code snippet. Please check it and let me know if any concern.